# Unit test results in NameError

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
import unittest
from blackjack import Blackjack
from blackjack import Player


class TestCardGame(unittest.TestCase):
    bj = Blackjack(4)

    def test_choose_card(self):
        self.assertEqual(bj.choose_card(['A',1],0),'A')
        self.assertEqual(bj.choose_card(['A', 1], 1), 1)

    def test_return_card_val(self):
        self.assertEqual(bj.return_card_val(['A',1],'A'),11)
        self.assertEqual(bj.return_card_val(['A',1], 1), 1)

class TestPlayer(unittest.TestCase):
    pl = Player('Apple')

    def test_add_score(self):
        self.assertEqual(pl.add_score('A'), 11)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get three NameErrors: NameError: name 'bj' is not defined 
Likewise for pl.

It seems I'm making a syntax error but I'm not sure where. First, I had missing arguments so I created instances of Blackjack and Player and now it doesn't seem to recognize the instances that I created.

Comment: It's not a syntax error but a logical one. Fix supplied below as an answer.

Comment: If you were making a syntax error, it would say `SyntaxError`. It says `NameError` because you are making a name error: that is, trying to use the name `bj` in a place where it is not in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling them from a bound method so access them as instance/class variables, or in other words access them using `self`

```
import unittest
from blackjack import Blackjack
from blackjack import Player


class TestCardGame(unittest.TestCase):
    bj = Blackjack(4)

    def test_choose_card(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.bj.choose_card(['A',1],0),'A')
        self.assertEqual(self.bj.choose_card(['A', 1], 1), 1)

    def test_return_card_val(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.bj.return_card_val(['A',1],'A'),11)
        self.assertEqual(self.bj.return_card_val(['A',1], 1), 1)

class TestPlayer(unittest.TestCase):
    pl = Player('Apple')

    def test_add_score(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.pl.add_score('A'), 11)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```